# Can no longer access Admin panel

Tags: wp-admin

Suddenly, I cannot get into my Admin panel.  When I enter the URL, it will only bring up the home page.  Any suggestions?  https://www.smokymountainsanytime.com/wp-admin/

Answer (score 0):

If you’re unable to access the login page of your WordPress site, it might be because your wp-login.php file was moved or deleted. To fix the problem, you need to reupload this file.

If you have the wrong file permissions for the wp-login.php file and wp-admin folder, that can make you unable to access the WordPress dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use your hosting File Manager to see if the wp-admin folder is actually there. And look at htaccess to see if it is set up properly.

You can try a manual re-install of WP via FTP. There are instructions out there on how to do that. Make a backup copy of your wp-config.php file first - that contains the credentials for database access.

You might also look for any files (plugin) that shouldn't be there. And check that there aren't additional admin accounts that shouldn't exist.